# Request-Path with PHP

Tags: php, email, return-path

I am trying to use the Request-Path header with the PHP `mail()` function, but it doesn't work. The Return-Path keeps on being changed to the From header.

From googling, I found useful tips, but none of them worked for me, though I learned many things.

Here is the very simple code I am using :

```
$headers ='From: "Marty"<from_param@gmail.com>'."\r\n";
//$headers .='Return-Path: return_path@gmail.com'."\r\n";
$headers .='Reply-To: reply_to@gmail.com'."\r\n";
$headers .='Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\r\n";
$headers .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';

$returnPath = '-freturn_path@gmail.com';

if (mail('goldorak_loves_albator@gmail.com', 'My subject', 'My body', $headers, $returnPath)) {
    echo 'Message sent';
} else {
    echo 'Message not sent';
}
```

And here is what I tried so far :

- with `\n` and `\r\n` as line feeds in the header
- with the Return-Path in the `$header` string
- with the Return-Path as the 5th parameter of the `mail()` function
- with Return-Path both in `$headers` and in `$returnPath`
- with and without a space in the `$returnPath` variable after `-f`
- with `-r` in the `$returnPath`, with and without a space, with and without `-f`

As I have read, there could be some problems with the exim configuration which replaces the Return-Path by the PHP user. But this is not the case here, as it is replaced by the `From` header.

I am nearly sure this is a configuration thing, as this code is very simple, but I cannot find anything useful...

Thank you for your help !

EDIT :
We don't use Exim on our Linux server, so the problem does not come from there.
I tried to achieve the same goal with SwiftMailer, but to no avail. The Return-Path is still ignored....

```
require('swift/lib/swift_required.php');

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
->setUsername('username@gmail.com')
->setPassword('myPassword');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
->setTo(array('goldorak_loves_albator@gmail.com'))
->setFrom(array('from@gmail.com' => 'Myself'))
->setReturnPath('return_path@gmail.com')
->setBody('Here is the message itself')
;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

This is directly taken from SwiftMailer example.

Comment: I think return path will be set by server.

Comment: Are you using Windows? In the documentation it says: "The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows."

Comment: The exim docs say that only trusted users can set that `-f` option, but you can set `untrusted_set_sender` to allow the option to untrusted users.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: No, my PHP server is under Debian. I am going to look for this 'truster users' thing and keep you informed, thanx for the tip

Comment: I just edited my original post to include a test I made with SwiftMailer, that ended up with the same result...